# How can i enter value into select/option from django model?

Tags: python, django

this is my first question here.

I've a model that looks like this;

```
class Fund(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False, blank=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, blank=False)
    management_price = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    performance_price = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    explanation = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
```

And i want to show all Fund names in a select area in the template here;

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
   <label>Fon*</label>
      <select id="fundIdSelect" class="form-control select2">
         <option value="0">Lütfen Fon Seçiniz</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

And this my relevant views.py;

```
def privacy(request):
   fund_list = Fund.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'privacy.html', context={'fund_list': fund_list})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the queryset in template. (I am assuming you want names in drop down.)

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
   <label>Fon*</label>
      <select id="fundIdSelect" class="form-control select2">
         {% for i in fund_list %}
         <option value="{{ i.name }}">{{ i.name }}</option>
         {% endfor %}
       </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but somehow it returns completely empty into the select field

Comment: Then 1) Check CSS in template. Try this with normal html tags without any css. 2)print queryset "fund_list " in view and check if it's empty.

Comment: Allright turns out i've been using it in the wrong view def, thanks to the print idea i found out.

Answer (score 0):

You suppose to run a for loop in your `privacy.html` file like this with your div tag:

```
{% for funds in fund_list  %}
       {{ funds }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Similiar to sanddeep's answer but it returns nothing to select field